# MongoDB C# filter wrapper

Tags: c#, mongodb

With the C# driver of MongoDB, we can do the following:
if you are dealing with a type *T* that has the field *_.id*, you can build a filter like this:

```
var F = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(_ => _._id, Value);
```

I need to make a function selects a field of T, like the *_ => _.id* part does, as a parameter that would work like that:

```
myfunc<T>(SOMETYPETHATSELECTSAFIELDOFT N, string V)
{
    var F = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(N, V);
}
```

I know that MongoDB supports passing the fields by name, but in this case I can not use that.

I'm having a look at Mongo's C# driver, but I can't really understand how it is done.

Comment: Why don't you want to use fluent inteface? mycollection.Find(x=>x.MyProperty =="MyValue")  What is your usecase? Sure you could build an expression, that get your property by the name, the question is, if you really need it-

Comment: have you tried to put a where cluase on your method where you maybe implement and interface who have the property string _id ..so every class T who been passed to your method need to have these interface and the field _id?

Comment: @Maksim: I haven't thought at all about the fluent interface, I'll give it a look; the use case here is that 1) people should use directly the field name, verified by the compiler as we had mistakes in the past when typing the name as a string and 2) some calls may actually not go to mongo at all (and I'll need to find which field we need to handle, as a secondary problem)

Comment: @federico: the issue is not whether or not T has a _id member, but rather how to pass a reference to a specific member of T (_id in the example).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using:

```
myfunc(Expression<Func<T, string>> N, string V)
```

I post the answer instead of closing the question as I didn't see this documented anywhere and it may help someone.